# How to create an Array of Protocol Buffer Messages in C

Tags: c, multithreading, buffer, protocols, calloc

BEFORE YOU READ: The calloc you'll see that I use to initialize the buffer is what's causing the problem, but I still don't know why. Statically defining the buffer array fixes the problem as you'll see if you keep reading...

I'm writing a UDP server that is made up of 2 threads: a receive and parse thread. The receive thread listens to the socket using recvfrom and pushes the messages it receives to the received_msgs_buf array. The parse thread pops from the received_msgs_buf array and decides what to do with it.

The received_msgs_buf array is protected by a mutex, and a semaphore signals the parse message thread to try and pop a message off the array. The problem is, every time I try to push a message I received into the received_msgs_buf I get a segfault.

Here is how I allocated memory for the buffer:

```
// this is in the header file
extern UXIMessage::Wrapper* received_msgs_buf;

// this is in the main.cpp file that calls pthread_create()
UXIMessage::Wrapper* received_msgs_buf;

// This is in the init function for the receive thread, defined in the udp.cpp file
received_msgs_buf = (UXIMessage::Wrapper*)calloc(MAX_NUM_MSGS_IN_QUEUE, sizeof(UXIMessage::Wrapper));
```

Here is my push function called in the receive thread:

```
void push_to_receive_buf(UXIMessage::Wrapper uxi_msg) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&received_msgs_mutex);
  if( num_received_msgs < MAX_NUM_MSGS_IN_QUEUE ) {
    printf("Message to put in buffer = %s\n", uxi_msg.DebugString().c_str());
    printf("Num received messages = %d\n", num_received_msgs);
    printf("Buf = %d\n", received_msgs_buf);
            // THE FOLLOWING LINE SEGFAULTS
    received_msgs_buf[num_received_msgs++] = uxi_msg;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&received_msgs_mutex);
  sem_post(&received_msgs_sem);
}
```

From the print statements I can see that the number of received messages is properly initialized to 0, the received message is perfectly valid and the buffer pointer is not NULL. Here's the print out:

Message to put in buffer = message_id: OCU_HEARTBEAT
ocu_heartbeat {
  ocu_id: 4747
}

Num received messages = 0

Buf = 778112

The segfault occurs in the CopyFrom() function, which is what's called by the = operator.

Edit: It's late, but I'll try just using a C++ std::vector tomorrow...

Edit2: For clarification, the mutexes and semaphores are all initialized properly in the main function as follows:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&received_msgs_mutex);
pthread_mutex_init(&msgs_to_send_mutex);
sem_init(&received_msgs_sem, 0, 0);
sem_init(&msgs_to_send, 0, 0);
```

EDIT3: THE PROBLEM IS THE CALLOC. When I statically define the received_msgs_buf as follows:

```
 // this is in the header file
extern UXIMessage::Wrapper received_msgs_buf[MAX_NUM_MSGS_IN_BUF];

// this is in the main.cpp file that calls pthread_create()
UXIMessage::Wrapper received_msgs_buf[MAX_NUM_MSGS_IN_BUF];
```

the code works...does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with the calloc?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see initialization of your mutex variable received_msgs_mutex 
- nor static, nor by pthread_mutex_init(). So, maybe initial value is wrong.

Second, you doing something with semaphore... 
Also, no info about initialization, or lock it.

So, did not provided enough info for reproduce your error or analyze code. 
Please, write isolated test, and share here. 
Or, you can just download my interthread queue, and use it for free:

http://olegh.cc.st/Queue.cpp.txt

It works.

Comment: It's not a problem w/ the semaphore or mutexes, it's a problem with the array of protocol buffer messages. The mutex and semaphores are both initialized in the main function using pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_name) and sem_init(&sem, 0, 0)

Comment: I'll try to add an isolated test case tomorrow so the error can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

well, even if the question is pretty old, someone may stumble over it just like I did, so I give my 2 cents:
If you calloc() your buffer BEFORE spawning, you surely get one message through, but I doubt, that it will run stable for a simple cause, that will take you some hours of research to understand:
Even if you protect your "shared" buffers and buffer counters from parallel access, you still have the problem, that one thread doesn't know, that another thread changed something. So it will CACHE memory content (by software algorithm as well as by hardware) and will see things that aren't true anymore.
Even if you fix some things by misusing "volatile" (which is meant for reading of hardware registers etc. and won't protect complete class instances) you will still stumble over compiler optimizations (instruction ordering) as well as over hardware multi-pipelining etc. which will again kill your logic.

Read about "memory barriers", understand them and then your (new) code will probably work.